# Universal Property to describe natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, category-theory, universal-property

In category theory I have seen two universal properties for natural numbers. In the category of Peano structures, that is structures such that the objects are triplets $(S,e,f)$ where $S$ is a set, $e$ is a basepoint element and $f$ is an endofunction. A morphism between $(S,e,f)$ and $(T,g,h)$ is a function $\varphi:S\to T$ such that $\varphi(e)=g$ and $\varphi\circ f = h\circ \varphi$. Then in this category the set $\Bbb N$ is the initial object.

In this category the universal property it satisfies basically garantuees, from my understanding at least, that the set has the property of induction to it. That is if $0\in A\subseteq \Bbb N$ and $n\in A\implies S(n)\in A$ then $A=\Bbb N$. I have read a few proofs that shows that the property of induction over natural numbers and the category theory property of being initial in such a category are equivalent.

Now in the category of Unital semirings with unit preserving homomorphisms we have that natural numbers are again an initial object. Which makes sense as how the homomorphisms would work and how multiplication and addition is defined for natural numbers.

Now the Peano category definition gives us the induction property, the Unital Semiring category one gives us the algebraic structure of natural numbers. Neither gives directly the other so my question is more on how we define it categoricly such that we get both?

My thoughts on the matter is that one could use a functor of some sort, seems the most natural doesn't it? I had an idea for a functor from the category of unital semirings etc to the peano category by having for an object $S$ in the semiring category it is sent to the object $(S,0_S,f)$ where $f(x)=x+1$ in the semiring. This works nicely with natural numbers and for any semiring we have this working, as it is unital semirings we are garantueed they have a $1$, naturally I also assume they have a $0$. For a semiring homomorphism $\varphi$ we have that we can take the corresponding set function, as we have 
$$\varphi(f(x))=\varphi(x+1)=\varphi(x)+1=h(\varphi(x))$$
so it sends homomorphisms of our initial category to morphisms of the other. The case of preserve fixed points is trivial from definition of unital homomorphisms.

I feel intuitively this would distinguish the natural numbers uniquely to include both the algebraic structure and induction property in a more category theoretical sense. My gut feeling is however that there should be a "backward" functor to go from peano to unital semirings. The issue there was I could not define it in any meaningful sense as the successor function could be defined as $f(x)=e$, the constant function to the fixed point, and as such a meaningful addition and multiplication from it would not be possible.

Is my thoughts on this correct or am I off? I know my understanding of adjoint functors is sorely lacking and trying to grasp them, as said my gut feeling it should be here too I just do not know how to do it. Anyhow is this correct? If not are there any good sources for linking the two together?

Comment: Are you familiar with [NNO's](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object)?

Comment: I am not, I will check it out.

Comment: @StefanPerko The first description is the description of an NNO (in $\mathbf{Set}$), though it certainly may be useful to realize that the characterization works in any category with a terminal object (though, of course, the NNO may fail to exist).

Comment: @DerekElkins You are right. I just wanted to let Zelos know about this terminology for reference purposes.

Comment: Thanks for it, greatly appriciated but it does from my understanding not connect the two parts as i desired.

Comment: Actually, while an initial Peano structure cannot have a proper subobject
(as in any category), there are plenty of Peano structures that are not
initial but still without proper subobjects. Just take $(\{0\},0,id)$.
So, recursion is strictly stronger than induction.

Comment: @MarcOlschok i lost where that enters into the topic at hand

Comment: @ZelosMalum sorry, I have not visited the site for quite a while. It was
just a comment on your above remark, that you have seen several proofs
that the universal property was equivalent to induction. But in fact:

Induction is equivalent to "no proper subobjects" and

Recursion is equivalent to "initial"